# How to list members of Keyvault in powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault

I am trying to find members of Keyvault and I am using the below command. But it returns only my access info, not all members of key vault.

```
Get-AzureRMKeyVault -VaultName MyVault
```

Need help on finding all members in a KeyVault.

Answer (score 1):

> finding all members in a KeyVault.

You could use `Get-AzureRMKeyVault` to get all key vaults in your current subscription.

BTW, the AzureRM will be deprecated, so recommend to use [`Get-AzKeyVault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvault?view=azps-3.0.0).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Az cmdlet

> $(Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName "vaultname").AccessPolicies

ARM cmdlet

> $(Get-AzureRMKeyVault -VaultName "vaultname").AccessPolicies